# Macbook shows ssd but volumes are gone after failing partition

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, partition, ssd, dual-boot

Okay so i had two volumes. One was 225gb osx and other 25 gb ubuntu. My ubuntu space was running low so i wanted to resize the partition. I clicked on osx volume and resized it. I gave ubuntu 100gb and rest to osx. I clicked partition and it said that Macintosh HD will be resized. 
Then partition failed. I rebooted in recovery mode to partition it from utility disk but it failed again. I rebooted and in dual mode couldn't find Macintosh HD. My ubuntu had failed before all this and was loading gnu grub before all this. That was the reason i wanted to resize ubuntu partition and reinstall ubuntu with a stable version.

[image: This is what it shows. Both childs are missing]

Is there anyway to bring back the volume?

If not:
I have installed osx on external drive and easeus shows my Macintosh HD and i have recovered 2gb of data. I want to recover at least 50 gb more. Any way i can do it for free?